# Java DatagramSocket setting keep-alive option

Tags: java, sockets, udp, keep-alive, datagram

I'm trying to create a datagramsocket with and datagrampacket to send with the keep-alive option. I'm confused about how to set this though. Is there a simple way to do it like `datagramsocket.setKeepAlive(true);` ?

EDIT: Sorry, I meant setting the time to live of a packet. Is there a way I can set it so if it isn't received, it will stay until it is received?

Comment: Which keep-alive option do you mean? You have to send your own UDP packets to keep the connection active in NAT routers and such.

Comment: I think you need to write down exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Keep-alive is an attribute of TCP (TCP packets); time-to-live (TTL) is an attribute of UDP (UDP datagrams and UDP multicast "packets".) Strangely, Java only exposes TTL for UDP multicast...

Comment: However, TTL and keep-alive are attributes of IP protocol in general.

Comment: @ee No. Keep-alive is an attribute of TCP only.

Comment: @EJP I did say like what you've said (minus the only) ;)

Comment: @ee. What you said is up there in black and white, and it isn't the same at all.

Comment: @EJP I am really surprised... Does mine `Keep-alive is an attribute of TCP;` not sound similar to yours `Keep-alive is an attribute of TCP (only)` ?? That is why I have a semicolon to break the idea between TCP and UDP. **Or**, are you referring to the my next comment regarding IP protocol? If yes, then it is my silly mistake.

Comment: @ee. Exactly. My 'No' applies to the immediately preceding comment. You could always delete it you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UDP is what's called connectionless protocol, i.e. no connection is established, you just send packets to an ip address/port tuple.  Since there is no connection, there is nothing to keep alive.

Comment: No I mean a Datagram packet, not a socket.

Comment: Do you mean time to live perhaps?

Comment: Like MK. has said, OP should look for TTL of UDP which is only provided by Java for UDP multicast [MulticastSocket.setTimeToLive() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html#setTimeToLive%28int%29), not for DatagramSocket. I wonder why...

Comment: You can have the "Conected UDP" mode on sockets (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#connect(java.net.SocketAddress)). The keepalive here has no meaning as the udp is stateless. You will have to implement a keepalive mechanism on your application.