# How to modify TTL value while sending UDP packet to ping a Host

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, ttl

I understand that TTL is a parameter in IP header.

I want to send a UDP packet to ping an IP address in JAVA. So far I can create UDP packet and send the packet to ping a remote IP in JAVA. And I am getting response from the destination server.

But I want to modify the TTL value. So far I could not find any method to modify TTL value in JAVA. If I change the TTL value the packet will not reach the destination and I can get a response from the last reachable hop.

This is the output what I am getting so far by sending an UDP packet to google.

```
root@JAVA# java udpICMP www.google.com 443

Sending: PING 0 24/09/18 15:27:42

Received from /172.217.17.36:443: 0�42 0 GNI time=24.0 ms

Sending: PING 1 24/09/18 15:27:42

Received from /172.217.17.36:443: 0�42 1 GNI time=23.0 ms
```

Can anyone help me to modify the time to live value in my java code.

I have used ***DatagramSocket*** and ***DatagramPacket*** class in my code. I have found that ***DatagramSocketImpl*** class has the method ***setTimeToLive(int ttl)*** to change Time to live manually. But ***DatagramSocketImpl*** is used for Multicast socket and also the method is *protected*. But I want to send unicast packet to ping if I am not wrong.

Comment: [Java DatagramSocket setting keep-alive option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675187/java-datagramsocket-setting-keep-alive-option)

Comment: @m4gic This is not my answer. As I have already mentioned at first that TTL is a value in IP header, I need some class working with IP header and ICMP protocol. The link you have provided discussing about time to live in UDP header.

Comment: @m4gic And I also want TTL option for UDP unicast packets. Not for multicasts.